# Android Retrofit Download/Reading Text File From Server

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, rx-java

How to download and read a text file using Retrofit or even better Rx Retrofit ?

Below is a sample how it was done before retrofit time.
really would be how to convert the code below in Retrofit
Sample:

```
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
    URL url = new URL("ksite.com/thefile.txt");

    // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
    }
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

I really Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:
There is a `@Streaming` annotation since version Retrofit 1.6 that can be used for delivering a raw `InputStream`. Can be used for downloading a file.

IMO Retrofit is not the best tool for downloading a file (unless the file contains JSON).

Using Retrofit (version 2) means you are using OkHttp under the hood. OkHttp is the better tool for downloading a file.

An asynchronous get with OkHttp looks like this:

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
        .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override public void onFailure(Request request, IOException throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
      }

      @Override public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
        for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
        }

        System.out.println(response.body().string());
      }
    });
  }
```

More in the [recipes section on Github](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes).

Also from the wiki:

> The string() method on response body is convenient and efficient for
>   small documents. But if the response body is large (greater than 1
>   MiB), avoid string() because it will load the entire document into
>   memory. In that case, prefer to process the body as a stream.

Edit:
Using RxJava

```
public interface Api {

    @Streaming
    @GET("path to file")
    Observable<ResponseBody> getFile();
}

api.getFile()
            .flatMap(responseBody -> {
                try {
                    return Observable.just(responseBody.string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return Observable.error(e);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Again you should probably not use `responseBody.string()` for bigger files.

Comment: Thanks, I will need to  process the body as a stream. Will try it

Comment: any chance can improve this code with AndroidRx ? thanks